# Cannot read property 'mData' of undefined error in editable datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatables

I just want to use jquery editable datatable with 4 more rows but I see this error : Cannot read property 'mData' of undefined .

If I put 4 `<th>` and 4 `<td>` datatable works good but if I put 5 or more `<th>` and `<td>` I get  ***Cannot read property 'mData' of undefined***

This is about row count ? Because td count equals tr count.

Code Examples ;

***Works***

```
<table class="table table-striped" id="datatable-editable">
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th>Rendering engine</th>
         <th>Browser</th>
         <th>Platform(s)</th>
         <th>Actions</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr class="gradeX">
         <td>Trident</td>
         <td>Internet
            Explorer 4.0
         </td>
         <td>Win 95+</td>
         <td class="actions">
            <a href="#" class="hidden on-editing save-row"><i class="fa fa-save"></i></a>
            <a href="#" class="hidden on-editing cancel-row"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a>
            <a href="#" class="on-default edit-row"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></a>
            <a href="#" class="on-default remove-row"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></a>
         </td>
         <td>dsa</td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

***Don't Work***

```
<table class="table table-striped" id="datatable-editable">
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th>Rendering engine</th>
         <th>Browser</th>
         <th>Platform(s)</th>
         <th>Actions</th>
         <th>**ExtraRow**</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr class="gradeX">
         <td>Trident</td>
         <td>Internet
            Explorer 4.0
         </td>
         <td>Win 95+</td>
         <td class="actions">
            <a href="#" class="hidden on-editing save-row"><i class="fa fa-save"></i></a>
            <a href="#" class="hidden on-editing cancel-row"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a>
            <a href="#" class="on-default edit-row"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></a>
            <a href="#" class="on-default remove-row"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></a>
         </td>
         <td>**Extra TD**</td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

JS :

```
(function( $ ) {

    'use strict';

    var EditableTable = {

        options: {
            addButton: '#addToTable',
            table: '#datatable-editable',
            dialog: {
                wrapper: '#dialog',
                cancelButton: '#dialogCancel',
                confirmButton: '#dialogConfirm',
            }
        },

        initialize: function() {
            this
                .setVars()
                .build()
                .events();
        },

        setVars: function() {
            this.$table             = $( this.options.table );
            this.$addButton         = $( this.options.addButton );

            // dialog
            this.dialog             = {};
            this.dialog.$wrapper    = $( this.options.dialog.wrapper );
            this.dialog.$cancel     = $( this.options.dialog.cancelButton );
            this.dialog.$confirm    = $( this.options.dialog.confirmButton );

            return this;
        },

        build: function() {
            this.datatable = this.$table.DataTable({
                "language": {
                    "decimal":        "",
                    "emptyTable":     "No data available in table",
                    "info":           "Showing _START_ to _END_ of _TOTAL_ entries",
                    "infoEmpty":      "Showing 0 to 0 of 0 entries",
                    "infoFiltered":   "(filtered from _MAX_ total entries)",
                    "infoPostFix":    "",
                    "thousands":      ",",
                    "lengthMenu":     "Show _MENU_ entries",
                    "loadingRecords": "Loading...",
                    "processing":     "Processing...",
                    "search":         "Search:",
                    "zeroRecords":    "No matching records found",
                    "paginate": {
                        "first":      "First",
                        "last":       "Last",
                        "next":       "Next",
                        "previous":   "Previous"
                    },
                },
                aoColumns: [
                    null,
                    null,
                    null,
                    { "bSortable": false }
                ]
            });

            window.dt = this.datatable;

            return this;
        },


        events: function() {
            var _self = this;

            this.$table
                .on('click', 'a.save-row', function( e ) {
                    e.preventDefault();

                    _self.rowSave( $(this).closest( 'tr' ) );
                })
                .on('click', 'a.cancel-row', function( e ) {
                    e.preventDefault();

                    _self.rowCancel( $(this).closest( 'tr' ) );
                })
                .on('click', 'a.edit-row', function( e ) {
                    e.preventDefault();

                    _self.rowEdit( $(this).closest( 'tr' ) );
                })
                .on( 'click', 'a.remove-row', function( e ) {
                    e.preventDefault();

                    var $row = $(this).closest( 'tr' );

                    $.magnificPopup.open({
                        items: {
                            src: _self.options.dialog.wrapper,
                            type: 'inline'
                        },
                        preloader: false,
                        modal: true,
                        callbacks: {
                            change: function() {
                                _self.dialog.$confirm.on( 'click', function( e ) {
                                    e.preventDefault();

                                    _self.rowRemove( $row );
                                    $.magnificPopup.close();
                                });
                            },
                            close: function() {
                                _self.dialog.$confirm.off( 'click' );
                            }
                        }
                    });
                });

            this.$addButton.on( 'click', function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();

                _self.rowAdd();
            });

            this.dialog.$cancel.on( 'click', function( e ) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $.magnificPopup.close();
            });

            return this;
        },

        // ==========================================================================================
        // ROW FUNCTIONS
        // ==========================================================================================
        rowAdd: function() {
            this.$addButton.attr({ 'disabled': 'disabled' });

            var actions,
                data,
                $row;

            actions = [
                '<a href="#" onclick="SaveItem();" class="hidden on-editing save-row"><i class="fa fa-save"></i></a>',
                '<a href="#" class="hidden on-editing cancel-row"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a>',
                '<a href="#" class="on-default edit-row"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></a>',
                '<a href="#" onclick="RemoveItem();" class="on-default remove-row"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></a>'
            ].join(' ');

            data = this.datatable.row.add([ '', '', '', actions ]);
            $row = this.datatable.row( data[0] ).nodes().to$();

            $row
                .addClass( 'adding' )
                .find( 'td:last' )
                .addClass( 'actions' );

            this.rowEdit( $row );

            this.datatable.order([0,'asc']).draw(); // always show fields
        },

        rowCancel: function( $row ) {
            var _self = this,
                $actions,
                i,
                data;

            if ( $row.hasClass('adding') ) {
                this.rowRemove( $row );
            } else {

                data = this.datatable.row( $row.get(0) ).data();
                this.datatable.row( $row.get(0) ).data( data );

                $actions = $row.find('td.actions');
                if ( $actions.get(0) ) {
                    this.rowSetActionsDefault( $row );
                }

                this.datatable.draw();
            }
        },

        rowEdit: function( $row ) {
            var _self = this,
                data;

            data = this.datatable.row( $row.get(0) ).data();

            $row.children( 'td' ).each(function( i ) {
                var $this = $( this );

                if ( $this.hasClass('actions') ) {
                    _self.rowSetActionsEditing( $row );
                } else {
                    $this.html( '<input type="text" class="form-control input-block" value="' + data[i] + '"/>' );
                }
            });
        },

        rowSave: function( $row ) {
            var _self     = this,
                $actions,
                values    = [];

            if ( $row.hasClass( 'adding' ) ) {
                this.$addButton.removeAttr( 'disabled' );
                $row.removeClass( 'adding' );
            }

            values = $row.find('td').map(function() {
                var $this = $(this);

                if ( $this.hasClass('actions') ) {
                    _self.rowSetActionsDefault( $row );
                    return _self.datatable.cell( this ).data();
                } else {
                    return $.trim( $this.find('input').val() );
                }
            });

            this.datatable.row( $row.get(0) ).data( values );

            $actions = $row.find('td.actions');
            if ( $actions.get(0) ) {
                this.rowSetActionsDefault( $row );
            }

            this.datatable.draw();
        },

        rowRemove: function( $row ) {
            if ( $row.hasClass('adding') ) {
                this.$addButton.removeAttr( 'disabled' );
            }

            this.datatable.row( $row.get(0) ).remove().draw();
        },

        rowSetActionsEditing: function( $row ) {
            $row.find( '.on-editing' ).removeClass( 'hidden' );
            $row.find( '.on-default' ).addClass( 'hidden' );
        },

        rowSetActionsDefault: function( $row ) {
            $row.find( '.on-editing' ).addClass( 'hidden' );
            $row.find( '.on-default' ).removeClass( 'hidden' );
        }

    };

    $(function() {
        EditableTable.initialize();
    });

}).apply( this, [ jQuery ]);
```

Comment: `th` count must be equal to `td` count per row, otherwise you have an invalid `table`.

Comment: Show your JS please

Comment: @Yuri I added JS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is due to `aoColumns` field. As stated [HERE](http://legacy.datatables.net/usage/columns)

> **aoColumns**: If specified, then the length of this array must be equal
>   to the number of columns in the original HTML table. Use 'null' where
>   you wish to use only the default values and automatically detected
>   options.

Then you will edit this field according to the number of th/td you have

```
...
aoColumns: [
    null,
    null,
    null,
    { "bSortable": false },
    null,
],
...
```